# Free Applications

Tags: pricebook

I have a simple question but I could not find the answer to it yet. I want to develop a Application for the Salesforce AppExchange but want to charge no price for it (Free App). So what costs do you I have to expect to pay to Salesforce? As far as I know Salesforce takes 15 (25) % of the revenue as a fee but as the App is free what do I have to pay to Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

The ISV (independent software vendor) partner program policy has the following definition of free for distribution:

> As part of the ISVForce Partner Category, Partners may distribute free applications to existing SFDC customers. Partner's distribution of free applications to existing SFDC customers does not require Partner to pay SFDC fees (other than Program Fees) for such distribution; provided, however, that an application is only a free application for the purposes of these Program Policies if the applicable customer can install and/or access and make full use of all of the features and capabilities of the application without paying Partner fees of any kind. A Partner application that integrates to or makes use of any application, service or other product for which Partner collects fees is not a free application. (For example, an application is not a free application if it is provided under a "freemium" payment model or if it requires purchase of another application from the applicable Partner.) SFDC reserves the right in its sole discretion and at any time to determine whether an application is a free application for the purposes of these Program Policies

which is separate from the security review and listing fee:

> If this is a paid offering, pay the annual listing fee and the one-time security review fee. If your app or component is free, these fees are waived.
>
> The initial Security Review fee is $2,550 USD for each paid app submitted (no fee for free apps).

and listing

**References**

- [AppExchange Partner Program Policies 2019 (pdf)](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/PartnerProgramPolicies.ProgramYear2019-2018.9.12.pdf)
- [AppExchange Partners: Security Review](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/Security_Review)
- [ISVForce Guide (pdf)](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf)